# Multiple TRIAC Dimmers Driving 1 load each on same circuit?

Tags: ceiling-fan, smart-switch

I've searched and searched and can't find my issue anywhere so thought I'd give this a shot.

I purchased a handful of these ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B086PPRWL7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086PPRWL7)) in hopes I could unify the fan/light setups in my house.

After installing them all, I noticed some odd behavior with 2 of them.  Incidentally, the two happen to share a common 15A circuit.  Different loads though so I never would have thought this was an issue.

Essentially, control of the lights from Fan A effect the lights of Fan B (but not vice versa).  I'm assuming Fan A is sooner in the circuit, then Fan B, then back to the breaker but I did not trace this out.

To summarize:

- Turning on the light of Fan A.  Light on Fan B will briefly turn on and then back off.
- Turning off the light of Fan A.  Light on Fan B will briefly turn on and then back off.
- Dimming the light of Fan A.  Light on Fan B will more or less following the dimming pattern of Fan A.

This behavior is not exhibited in the reverse.  Doing anything to Fan B does not influence Fan A at all.

Based on my understanding, this is happening because of the shared neutrals.  The product itself does not warn of this and their support blames my bulbs which are incandescent and should not be an issue.

Running another circuit to this room isn't terribly feasible as it's on the complete opposite end of the house.  Is there anything I can do or put into the junction box of Fan B to shield it from what's happening with Fan A?  I want to like the switch but this isn't a situation I can let happen.

EDIT: Switches behave pre-programmed as well so it's nothing in the "smart" aspect that has it doing this.

As I've just realized, it's not UL or ETL listed which is a requirement in my area so I guess I'm going to have to remove them all anyway.  Oh well.

Comment: 1) No indication that they're UL certified, so be prepared for consequences. 2) They're smart switches are you sure they're programmed correctly. 3) Please pull the switches from the wall _without disconnecting any wiring_ and take some clear, focused pictures of how the wiring is connected. It almost sounds like Switch B is downstream from Switch A, but one of the electricians here will likely see something wrong with the wiring.

Comment: Yeah, they're unsafe and illegal, you can't use them.  FCC certification doesn't even apply to  electrical safety, it's about radio emissions, and it's one of the 4 marks they often fake. (FCC, RoHS, CE, CCC).  What you need is a real testing lab cert: UL obviously, CSA or ETL. Unfortunately sellers have figured out that if they charge a high price people think their product is legit.

Comment: They behave this way without programming.  Just locally pushing the buttons even so it's definitely not that.

Comment: add a simple snubber circuit to each dimmer to prevent line disturbances; some cheap dimmers don't integrate them, but they can be added or doubled up as needed.

Comment: I ended up decided to return them.  I didn't notice they weren't UL/ETL listed and don't want to shoulder the risk.